# How can I solve like the following exercise that shows in the image

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

[image]

How can I solve like the following exercise that shows in the image

Comment: @martini of course you can solve like this exercise

Comment: Please type in the question using text and not using an image.  Using an image makes it longer to download the post and makes it impossible to search.

Comment: Please show the image that contains the exercise. Avoid using red letters. Best is to type it in using Latex avoiding image upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, suppose $T$ is bounded. Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $X$ converging to zero. Then, $\{\lVert x_n\rVert\}$ also converges to zero and hence is bounded (by some $M$). Thus, $\lVert Tx_n \rVert \leq \lVert T \rVert \lVert x_n \rVert \leq \lVert T \rVert M < \infty$.

Conversely, suppose $T$ maps zero-convergent sequences to bounded sequences. If $T$ were unbounded, we could find $x_n \in X$ such that $\lVert x_n \rVert = 1$ and $\lVert Tx_n \rVert \geq n$. Note then that $n^{-1/2}x_n$ converges to zero but $\lVert T(n^{-1/2}x_n) \rVert \geq n^{1/2}$ so $\{T(n^{-1/2}x_n)\}$ is unbounded, a contradiction. Hence, $T$ must be bounded.

Comment: Could you see the following link please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1232397/some-question-about-extension-of-bounded-linear-operator

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235782/orthogonal-in-inner-product-space#1235793