# Some question about extension of bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let we have the following bounded linear operator $$T: D(T)\rightarrow Y$$ such that $D(T)$ is the domain and it is a vector space and $Y$ is a Banach space . 
Then it has an extension $$H: E\rightarrow Y$$ such that $E=CL(D(T))$ .
Now the questions that present themselves : 
$1)$ if $D(T)$ then $E=CL(D(T))$ is a vector space ??? I want the proof 
$2)$ $D(T)$ is a vector space , can it to be not a closed set ? 
In other word it is necessary the vector space be closed set or not ? So $E=CL(D(T))$ isn't equal to $D(T)$ ? With example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question the above answer is good....

For the first one let $x,y \in \overline{D(T)}$, i.e., there exist sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ in $D(T)$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow x$ and $y_n \longrightarrow y$, then $(x_n+y_n)$ is a sequence in $D(T)$ (as $D(T)$ is a vector space) such that $x_n+y_n \longrightarrow x+y$ and if $\alpha$ is any scalar then $(\alpha x_n)$ is a sequence in $D(T)$ (as $D(T)$ is a vector space) such that $\alpha x_n \longrightarrow \alpha x$. Hence $x +y, \alpha x\in \overline{D(T)}$ and this shows that $\overline{D(T)}$ is indeed a vector space.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, the closure of a vector space is a vector space.
2. Yes, $D(T)$ might not be a closed set.

For example, polynomials form a non-closed subspace of $C[0,1]$ (the continuous functions on $[0,1]$).