# Orthogonal in inner product space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $(X,<.>)$ is an inner product space prove that $x$ and $y$  are orthogonal if and only if $||x+αy|| \ge ||x||$ for any scalar $α$ .
The first direction if $x$ and $y$  are orthogonal then$||x+αy||^2=||x||^2+|α|^2||y||^2 \ge ||x||^2 $ so $||x+αy|| \ge ||x||$ .
But the second direction if $||x+αy|| \ge ||x||$ for any scalar $α$ Implies $x$ and $y$  are orthogonal how can I prove that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\langle x+\alpha y,x+\alpha y\rangle\geq\langle x,x\rangle\forall \alpha\\
\langle x,x\rangle+2\alpha\langle x,y\rangle+\alpha^2\langle y,y\rangle\geq\langle x,x\rangle\forall\alpha\\
2\alpha \langle x,y\rangle+\alpha^2\langle y,y\rangle \geq0\forall\alpha$$
But the left-hand side equals zero if $\alpha=0$ and if $\alpha=-2\langle x,y\rangle/\langle y,y\rangle$.  If $\langle x,y\rangle\neq0$ then this is a quadratic in $\alpha$ which has two zeros, and will be negative for some $\alpha$.  In particular, $\alpha=-<x,y>/<y,y>$ makes the left-hand side equal to $-<x,y>^2/<y,y>$

Comment: I can't understand what do you mean

Comment: When I squared the inequality I got : $$2Re<x,αy>+|α|^2||y||^2 \ge 0 $$ how can I complete ?

Comment: $<x,y>$ isn't equal to $<y,x>$ because $<x,y>$ is the conjugate of $<y,x>$

Comment: Let $\alpha$ be such that $\langle x,\alpha y\rangle$ is real, then the first term becomes $2|\alpha||\langle x,y\rangle|$

Comment: @Empy2 but if you do so, then $\alpha$ isn't arbitrary any more. How can it be sure that the equation above still has two zeros.